# Finding the sign of a dot product

Tags: vectors

If $|\vec{a}|=2$,  $|\vec{b}|=5$  and $|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|=8$,
find $(\vec{a }\cdot\vec{b})$
Using $|\vec{a}\times\vec b|^2 + (\vec{a }\cdot\vec{b})^2=|\vec{a}|^2|\vec{b}|^2$
we get two answers +6 and -6. Are both of them correct or should we take the positive value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ that satisfy the given conditions, then replacing $\vec a$ by its inverse will flip the sign of $\vec a\cdot \vec b$, but leave the givens unchanged.

So you can't hope to find the sign of $\vec a\cdot \vec b$ based on those given values.

Answer (score 12):

This question is equal to say:

> One parallelogram has **sides** with lengths $2$ and $5$, and **area** $8$, what is the **angle** between them?

And it's clear that we have **two** answer:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The fact that $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are vectors is really a red herring.  With the  information given, the equation is $64+ x^2= 100$ so $x^2= 36$ which has roots x= 6 and x= -6.  There is no reason why the dot product of two vectors cannot be negative so both are solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are correct since $$\vec|a\times\vec b| = 8 \implies ||a||b|\sin\theta| = 8 \implies |sin \theta| = \frac{4}{5}$$
So $$\sin \theta = \pm \frac{4}{5} \implies \cos \theta = \pm \frac{3}{5}$$
Thus,$$(\vec a \cdot \vec b) = |a||b|\cos\theta = \pm 6$$

Comment: That's not really a valid argument that both signs are possible -- your calculations show (like the OPs do) that the dot product must be one of $-6$ and $6$, but not that both results are _possible_.

Answer (score 1):

You said this:

$$|\vec{a}\times\vec b|^2 + (\vec{a }\cdot\vec{b})^2=|\vec{a}|^2|\vec{b}|^2$$

But you did omit intermediate steps to reach the conclusion:

$|\vec{a}\times\vec b|^2 + (\vec{a }\cdot\vec{b})^2=|\vec{a}|^2|\vec{b}|^2\sin(\alpha)^2+|\vec{a}|^2|\vec{b}|^2\cos(\alpha)^2=|\vec{a}|^2|\vec{b}|^2(\sin(\alpha)^2+\cos(\alpha)^2)=|\vec{a}|^2|\vec{b}|^2$

The key here is the 1-sized circle equation relating sin and cos:

$$(\sin(\alpha)^2+\cos(\alpha)^2) = 1$$

So: **Provided you use always the same angle (i.e. the same order between vectors a and b), that will be true due to the identity**. If you have two different values, it is because you can choose to multiply a with b, or b with a (getting $\alpha = |\alpha|$ or $\alpha = -|\alpha|$). You must take that into account beforehand: $\alpha$ will be determined by the operands order, and will determine the sign of both products operations. **Finally**: Yes, both values will be valid depending on the quadrant of $\alpha$.